# Aligning a ChipGroup with an ImageView using ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-chips

I want to center align a ChipGroup beside an ImageView. Here is my XML:

```
...

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/locationIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_24dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/locationChips"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/locationIcon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/locationIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/locationIcon">

        </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

...
```

Expected Result:

[image: Expected Result]

Actual Result:

[image: Actual Result]

As you can see, the chips are not aligning and instead are on top of the title text and the last chip also overflows if the text is of a certain length. How can I fix this? Also, I have found that if the ChipGroup is constrained to the parent instead, the last chip does not overflow.

Comment: Add your expected output image

Comment: @backpack : added answer. let me know anything you want to change

Answer (score 1):

> Please remove ChipGroup bottom constraint and apply end constraint with width = "0dp"
>
> It will display like below image.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/locationIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon_location" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/locationChips"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/locationIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/locationIcon">

</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. This has fixed the chip overflow problem, but the icon is still not aligned: https://imgur.com/fOZcfxd

Comment: icon for chip is from google or you make it customise?

Comment: It's from Google.

Comment: Try one thing 
give this constarint to chipGroup :app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" 
and this constraint to imageview app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/locationChips"

Comment: It's the same. No change.

Comment: check any where you gave margin top? Programatically or in style ?